# Redirect deprecated function call to newer function

Tags: php

I have a fairly complex website, for which I'm upgrading the database driver to MySQLi (yeah, I know..). I've had some 20-ish function points where I rewrote the query-code which contains mysql_real_escape_string, but this is becoming a far to cumbersome job to do for the entire site.

Is there a way to "redirect" any call to mysql_real_escape_string to another function: mysqli_real_escape_string, including the current object/class from which the call is made?

```
<?php
  class foo {
    private $_sql;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->_sql = new db();
    }

    public function get_posts($id) {
      $this->_sql->query = 'select * from posts where id = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    }
  }
?>
```

Each class contains a sql property, that holds a db connection, but since mysqli_real_escape_string requires the connection passed as first argument, I would need a 'fetching' mechanism that redirects `mysql_real_escape_string` to something like:

```
function custom_mres($caller, $param) {
  return mysqli_real_escape_string($caller->_sql->connection, $param);
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Don't do it. `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not the right option either. You need to use prepared statements. If you have a chance to clean up old code, then do it properly. I would even recommend to switch to one of the DB abstraction libraries e.g. [EasyDB](https://github.com/paragonie/easydb) if it is feasible.

Comment: I know, things have to change in the core. In fact, the entire custom made framework thats about 12 years old now needs an upgrade to a modern framework like Laravel. But currently that's not an option due to time limitations. I will take a look at EasyDB and see if it is a solution. Fingers crossed..

Comment: Why not do a replace on `mysql_real_escape_string(` to `mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_sql, ` ???

Comment: @AbraCadaver A. Not a proper way to protect against SQL injection. B. Still uses procedural style C. Makes the code verbose without providing real benefits over prepared statements. D. Reversed order of operands -> easy to make a mistake.

Comment: @Dharman: Agreed, but obviously they aren't going to do it the proper way.  What is _Reversed order of operands_?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I meant parameters. The link object is expected either as a first or the second argument.

Comment: @Dharman: No, first only, the string is second.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to a later version of PHP where the mysql_* methods are now gone you should be able to redefine them, while it's not the optimal solution I fully understand why one would want a stop gap measure.

I would suggest using a static class to track the connection object, like so:

```
<?PHP
  class DBWrapper {
    static private $dbc;

    static public escape($str) {
      return mysqli_real_escape_string(self::$dbc, $str);
    }
  }

  if (!function_exists('mysql_real_escape_string'))
    function mysql_real_escape_string($str) { return DBWrapper::escape($str); }      
?>
```

**Note: I do not advocate keeping this workaround in place, you really should update your application to use the modern methods**

Another suggestion is to put a `error_log` call in there to flag for deprecated use allowing you to easily identify and correct it later, for example:

```
<?PHP
  define('LOG_DEPRECATED', 1);

  class DBWrapper {
    static private $dbc;

    static public escape($str) {
      if (defined('LOG_DEPRECATED'))
      {
        ob_start();
        print_r(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS));
        error_log("Deprecated call:\n", ob_get_clean());
      }
      return mysqli_real_escape_string(self::$dbc, $str);
    }
  }      
?>
```

Also, while @Dharman's suggestion to use prepared statements is good, it is not unsafe to manually escape if done correctly. Just be sure to set the connection and database encoding to sane values and `mysqli_real_escape_string` becomes safe to use, and in many cases faster as the database engine doesn't need to "prepare" a statement and return a handle/object before execution.